# Is there an IC with a large number of digitally controllable switches? And if so, how could I control it?

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

Okay so I'm looking for an IC or anything that contains a large number of controllable switches.

Say for instance, 100 switches.  Each switch must have an independent input and output.  I don't want to select from them, so I don't need a mux/demux.  I essentially want all 100 of them to be individually controllable, which I suppose would require 100 bits of control, so if an IC did exist it would have to be at least 300+ pins

Is there any way to do this? I'm doubtful that there's an IC that can do this, but maybe there's a solution I haven't heard of.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT with crosspoint**

So I realize I could connect different points to every other point with a crosspoint switch that had 2x as many pins as connection points, sort of like this.

[image]

But this results in a lot of wasted switches.  Out of the 16 switches in this 4x4 crosspoint, only 6 are needed, so 10 are wasted.

Optimally, I should only need 6, like so:

[image]

Also, I think it's possible to connect by using a cross point that has the same amount of total IO as connection points I need, like this:

[image]

But to connect any point back to the same side, I would have to use up one of the points on the other side. Like {A-C-B}

Comment: Can you use an FPGA?

Comment: What are you switching? Logic? Analog? ... specs needed

Comment: Analog, but very low current, so preferably analog switches.  Yeah I could use an FPGA, but I don't know how to get around the lack of I/O problem.  100 switches would need 100 inputs, 100 outputs, 100 control bits, and whatever else

Comment: Maybe this could work? http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-crosspoint-switches/ad75019/products/product.html

Comment: I was going to say cross point switches like you suggest, similar work I've seen for very low level signals (for SQUIDS) used reed relays that were shielded.  Huge board area.

Comment: Does it have to be in one giant package, or can you just spread it across lots of little ones? ie daisy chain http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-switches/adg714/products/product.html or http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX335.pdf

Comment: For a 100 switch part you could significantly reduce the number of required I/O pins if the 100 control sugnals were on-chip and driven from the outputs of a serial register scheme. Such register could be loaded via an I2C or SPI interface.

Comment: Here is a quad bilateral switch part datasheet (*.pdf) http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4016_CNV.pdf

Comment: It could be multiple smaller packages.  I'm also a little confused, because I'm not sure if that cross-point is really what I want.  That IC comes with 32 IO pins, and 16^2 addressable switches.  I basically need something that connects a number of points in a circuit to any and/or all other similar connection points in the circuit.  Say there was 4 connection points, A,B,C,D.  Then I would need 1+2+3 switches, to cover all combinations. {A-B}, {A-C}, {A-D}, {B-C}, {B-D}, and {C-D}  That's only 6 switches for 4 connection points.  How do I get that out of a crosspoint?

Comment: A 4 input, 4 output crosspoint would have 4^2, so 16 switches, but I only need 6. So if I connected A,B,C, and D to both the inputs and the outputs, Am I forced to waste switches with redundant cases? Like {A-A}, {B-B}, and so on?

Comment: You need each of the 100 switches to connect to each of the 100 outputs individually? Do they all need to be active at the same time? You said 100 was an example, how many do you actually need?

Comment: Yes, I would want each IO pin to possibly connect to every other IO pin, and not exclusively, so they could connect to any number of others.  I just used the {A,B,C,D} as a simpler example.  I don't really know how many I would need, I would just like to know how many would be practical or possible.

Comment: Check out my updates to the question, that might help explain a bit

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve at the next higher level? There might be better alternatives than your crossbar approach. If you want to crossbar low-frequency analog one /approach would be to do A/D conversion, then routing in a processor, then D/A conversion.

Comment: Sure, so my original idea may be a little bit off from what you're expecting.  I actually had the idea to make a programmable breadboard, so maybe I should have said that sooner.  I just need the ability to connect different circuit points.  I just recently found this similar question, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24458/programmable-point-to-point-connections which seems to suggest it isn't feasible.  I'd still love to if it's possible, so I'm still open to input

Answer (score 1):

For individual control, twenty-five [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf) switches would work for you.  They are about $0.50/ea from a distributor.  Or cheaper from China, Futurelec, etc.

If you are controlling this from a microcontroller, it will be more convenient to set up a daisy-chain of thirteen [ADG714](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADG714_715.pdf)s, and control them via SPI bus.  These are almost $5 each from distributors, but the switches themselves have better specs.

The cheapskate microcontroller solution is to use the CD4066 switches but control them with digital shift registers like a chain of thirteen [74hc595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf).